# Named pipe communication in C

Tags: c, pipe, named-pipes

> EDIT:  I just realised I've entered a double block (I've first opened
>   fifoR on both, but fifoR is the oposite on each). corrected that and
>   established communication! (CODE BELOW IS FIXED).

I'm trying to create a client-server app, in which the server forks and the child uses named pipes as stdin and stdout to communicate with the client.
It's my first program utilizing named pipes, so I'm probably missing something basic, but I can't tell what (possibly a bunch of stuff)

Here are my codes (compile with no errors and a similar code but using TCP sockets instead of named pipes is running splendid).

Server Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define FIFO_R "./tmp/myfifoR"
#define FIFO_W "./tmp/myfifoW"

void fatal(const char *msg);
void child_process(int fdr,int fdw);

int main()
{
    int fdr,fdw;
    char *myfifor = FIFO_R;
    char *myfifow = FIFO_W;
    int status;

    /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
    if ( mkfifo(myfifor, 0666) < 0 ) 
    {
        fatal("fifoR");
    }
    if ( mkfifo(myfifow, 0666) < 0 )
    {
        fatal("fifoW");
    }
    printf("openning fifoR\n");
    if( (fdr = open(myfifor, O_RDONLY)) < 0 )
        fatal("opening fdr");
    printf("fifoR unblocked\n");
    printf("openning fifoW\n");
    if( (fdw = open(myfifow, O_WRONLY)) < 0 )
        fatal("opening fdw");
    printf("fifoW unblocked\n");
    switch(fork())
    {
        case 0:
            child_process(fdr,fdw);
        case -1:
            fatal("child creation");
        default:    
            printf("parent\n");
            close(fdr);
            close(fdw);
            wait(&status);
            unlink(myfifor);
            unlink(myfifow);
            printf("all clean, exiting\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void fatal(const char *msg)
{
    printf("%s\n",msg);
    perror(msg);
    exit(-1);
}


#define APP "./calc/calc"
void child_process(int fdr,int fdw)
{
    printf("child\n");
    close(0);
    close(1);
    close(2);
    if( dup(fdr) != 0 || dup(fdw) != 1 || dup(fdw) != 2 )
        fatal("dup sockets");
    execl(APP,"",(char*)NULL);
    fatal("execl");
}
```

Client Code (FIXED):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define FIFO_W "./tmp/myfifoR"
#define FIFO_R "./tmp/myfifoW"
#define EXIT_CHAR 'q'
#define MAX_BUF 1024

void fatal(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(-1);
}

int main()
{   
    int fdr,fdw;
    char *myfifor = FIFO_R;
    char *myfifow = FIFO_W;
    char buff[MAX_BUF];
    char c;

/* the order of this opens was inversed to the order in server, so it resulted in a deadlock */
    printf("openning fifoR\n");
    if( (fdw = open(myfifow, O_WRONLY)) < 0 )
        fatal("opening fdw");
    printf("fifoR unblocked\n");
/* */

    printf("openning fifoW\n");
    if( (fdr = open(myfifor, O_RDONLY)) < 0 )
        fatal("opening fdr");
    printf("fifoW unblocked\n");
    /*  first strings   */
    memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
    read(fdr,buff,sizeof(buff));
    printf("%s\n",buff);
    while( (c = getchar()) != EXIT_CHAR )
    {
        write(fdw,&c,1);
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
            read(fdr,buff,sizeof(buff));
            printf("%s",buff);
        }
    };
    close(fdw);
    close(fdr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Is ther some problem then?

Comment: For the future: Please always explain what doesn't work. Your question implies that there is a problem, but you don't explain what the problem actually is. Now that you found a solution, would you do us the favour and post it below so we can all enjoy it?

Comment: I've edited the solution in the code, the above code is working.
Would it be more clear if I posted it on the comment section?
(and I really didn't know what the problem was, nothing really responded)

Comment: You should edit this question back to its original state and instead post your solution and explanation of it in the answer section below. This way, people who come across your question looking for a solution of their own can see what your actual question was. These questions aren't just for you, but for future readers who have the same problem and find your question.